# JavaFX WebView GetLoadWorker StateProperty reporting SUCCEEDED before page loads

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I want to snap a picture of a webpage using the JavaFX "snapshot" method.  My problem is that the WebView doesn't load the webpage before I snap the snapshot.  Putting the call to snapshot inside a listener that tests when the webview's getLoadWorker succeeds doesn't work.  I get inside the "if" of the listener (see below) before the page actually loads.

To demonstrate this, the following standalone code both attempts to snap the snapshot upon "success" and allows you to click a button to do the same.  The button click (marked "BUTTON") works, because you click it after the webpage loads.  However the automatic snapshot (marked "AUTOMATIC") produces a blank image, because for some reason the worker state is reaching "SUCCEEDED" before the page is actually loaded.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the getLoadWorker listener?  Thank you for any help!

```
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OpenHTML extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final VBox vbox = new VBox(2);
        final Button btn = new Button();

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.setMaxWidth(600);
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        File myHTMLFile = new File("C:/Temp/test.html");

        try {
            webEngine.load(myHTMLFile.toURI().toURL().toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState,
                            State newState) {
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            System.out.println("succeeded");
                            // AUTOMATIC
                            snapit(vbox, "snapshot_auto.png");
                        }
                    }
                }); 

        vbox.getChildren().add(btn);
        vbox.getChildren().add(webView);
        btn.setText("Snap a picture");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 // BUTTON
                 snapit(vbox, "snapshot_by_btn.png");
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(vbox), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void snapit(VBox vbox, String filename) {
        WritableImage snapshot = vbox.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null); 
        File file = new File("C:/Temp/" + filename);
        RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OpenHTML.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing (and I mean guessing) the engine has loaded (and probably parsed) the html, but the web view hasn't had a chance to render it as no rendering frame has occurred. Try wrapping the call to `snapit` in a `Platform.runLater(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The Oracle doc says that the runnables are executed in the order they are posted, which is perfect, but it still doesn't work.  For example, if I put the scene in a Platform.runLater() and then the call to snapit in a subsequent Platform.runLater(), the actual web content is still displayed afterwards.  

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: There's definitely a timing issue.  All functional examples I've found use a rather arbitrary sleep through the use of a Java FX `PauseTransition`.  Agreed, `Platform.runLater(...)` just masks the underlying timing issue and doesn't work 100% of the time.  I can also confirm what @James_D is saying, if I use `getEngine().executeScript(...)` to query the DOM, the items that don't show up in the snapshot are indeed loaded, but apparently something in the paint routine is just a few clicks behind from be ready before the snapshot.